# Sample application with imgui library generate error

Tags: c++, imgui

I am new in imgui and just installed it with vcpkg and created an application in vs2022 and add these codes:

```
#include <imgui.h>
using namespace std;

void MySaveFunction()
{
}

int main()
{
    ImGui::Text("Hello, world %d", 123);
    if (ImGui::Button("Save"))
        MySaveFunction();
}
```

but when I run this application I get this error:

[image]

What minimum code do I need to display a window with a button on it?

I searched on the IMGUI website but could not find any simple sample that works.

Comment: https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dear ImGui provided some detailed [examples](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/tree/master/examples) on how to get started.

Don't be scared to read the code, which might be long and overwhelming if you are new to it.

You basically need to choose a [backend](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/master/docs/BACKENDS.md), I personally prefer DirectX 11. Then you have to [create a window and initialize DirectX](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/master/examples/example_win32_directx11/main.cpp#L31). Then [create the ImGuiContext](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/master/examples/example_win32_directx11/main.cpp#L47) - which throws the error for `g` is nullptr because the context wasn't created, and [initialize the backend](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/master/examples/example_win32_directx11/main.cpp#L57) after that.

Comment: I am using vcpkg and the documentation for this library stated that it is header only application. How can I build it using vcpkg and select a suitable backend? Adding CPP is not possible with vcpkg.

Comment: @mans take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70254678/installing-dear-imgui-with-vcpkg-on-windows-10)